# How do I increment the marks for each correct question in a Java MCQ Application

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, swing

I'm trying to make a QUIZ Application where everytime where the questions are retrieved from the DB,Each time the user selects the right option his marks should be incremented.
While I'm trying to do that the marks doesnt seem to increase and sometimes end up staying at zero even If I select the right option.

This whole project is being done on Eclipse using WindowBuilder. I would be grateful if anyone helped me out on this.

```
package quiz;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.*; 
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import java.sql.*; 
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import quiz.SqlConnection;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

public class QuizStart extends JFrame {
SqlConnection c1= new SqlConnection();
public int tmarks=0;
public int db_marks;
String studentAnswer="";
String db_ans="";
static String username="";
String usern;
int count=0;
private JPanel contentPane;
/**
 * Launch the application.
 */

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                QuizStart frame = new QuizStart(username);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 * @param username2 
 * @param username 
 */
//public QuizStart() {
    //initComponents();
//}
public QuizStart(String username) {
        //initComponents();
        usern=username;
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 950, 631);
    
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    
    JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
    menuBar.add(mnFile);
    
    JMenuItem mntmBack = new JMenuItem("Back");
    mntmBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            new Login().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    mnFile.add(mntmBack);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBackground(new Color(30, 144, 255));
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    
    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("New label");
    lblNewLabel.setBackground(new Color(30, 144, 255));
    lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(101, 47, 715, 99);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);
    
    JRadioButton radioButton = new JRadioButton("New radio button");
    radioButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        }
    });
    radioButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    radioButton.setBounds(124, 213, 230, 47);
    contentPane.add(radioButton);
    
    JRadioButton radioButton_1 = new JRadioButton("New radio button");
    radioButton_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    radioButton_1.setBounds(125, 289, 254, 60);
    contentPane.add(radioButton_1);
    
    JRadioButton radioButton_2 = new JRadioButton("New radio button");
    radioButton_2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    radioButton_2.setBounds(418, 201, 254, 71);
    contentPane.add(radioButton_2);
    
    JRadioButton radioButton_3 = new JRadioButton("New radio button");
    radioButton_3.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    radioButton_3.setBounds(418, 289, 303, 60);
    contentPane.add(radioButton_3);
    
    JButton btnNext = new JButton("Next");
    btnNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                
                Statement str1= c1.con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs=str1.executeQuery("select Question,Option1,Option2,Option3,Option4,CorrectOption,Marks from question ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10");
                while(rs.next())
                {   
                    
                    String v1=rs.getString("Question");
                    String v2=rs.getString("Option1");
                    String v3=rs.getString("Option2");
                    String v4=rs.getString("Option3");
                    String v5=rs.getString("Option4");
                    db_ans=rs.getString("CorrectOption");
                    db_marks=rs.getInt("Marks");
                     
                    lblNewLabel.setText(v1);
                    radioButton.setText(v2);
                    radioButton_1.setText(v3);
                    radioButton_2.setText(v4);
                    radioButton_3.setText(v5);
                    System.out.print("second");
                }
                if(radioButton.isSelected())
                {
                    studentAnswer=radioButton.getText();
                    radioButton_1.setSelected(false);
                    radioButton_2.setSelected(false);
                    radioButton_3.setSelected(false);
                    
                }
                else if(radioButton_1.isSelected())
                {
                    studentAnswer=radioButton_1.getText();
                    radioButton.setSelected(false);
                    radioButton_2.setSelected(false);
                    radioButton_3.setSelected(false);
                    
                }
                else if(radioButton_2.isSelected())
                {
                    studentAnswer=radioButton_2.getText();
                    radioButton.setSelected(false);
                    radioButton_1.setSelected(false);
                    radioButton_3.setSelected(false);
                }
                else {
                    studentAnswer=radioButton_3.getText();
                    radioButton.setSelected(false);
                    radioButton_1.setSelected(false);
                    radioButton_2.setSelected(false);
                }
                if(db_ans.equals(studentAnswer))
                {
                    
                    tmarks=tmarks+db_marks;
                    System.out.println("correct-second");
                    
                }
                
                count++;
                //System.out.println(count);
                //System.out.println("two");
                System.out.println(tmarks);
                if(count == 11)
                {
                    btnNext.setEnabled(false);
                }
                //for(int i = qhist.size()-1;i>=0; i--){
                //     System.out.println(qhist.get(i));
                //}
                
            }
            catch(Exception s) {
                System.out.println("Error due to :"+s);
            }
        }
    });
    btnNext.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    btnNext.setBounds(338, 440, 159, 60);
    contentPane.add(btnNext);
    
    JButton btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
    btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            new QuizResult(usern,tmarks).setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    btnSubmit.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    btnSubmit.setBounds(706, 524, 159, 60);
    contentPane.add(btnSubmit);
    
    JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("New label");
    lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(48, 10, 184, 27);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_1);
    lblNewLabel_1.setText(username);
    
    try {
        
        Statement str= c1.con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=str.executeQuery("select QID,Question,Option1,Option2,Option3,Option4,CorrectOption,Marks from question ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10");
        while(rs.next())
        {   
            //qhist.push(rs.getInt("QID"));
            String v1=rs.getString("Question");
            String v2=rs.getString("Option1");
            String v3=rs.getString("Option2");
            String v4=rs.getString("Option3");
            String v5=rs.getString("Option4");
            db_ans=rs.getString("CorrectOption");
            db_marks=rs.getInt("Marks");
             
            lblNewLabel.setText(v1);
            radioButton.setText(v2);
            radioButton_1.setText(v3);
            radioButton_2.setText(v4);
            radioButton_3.setText(v5);
            System.out.print("first");
        }
        if(radioButton.isSelected())
        {
            studentAnswer=radioButton.getText();
            radioButton_1.setSelected(false);
            radioButton_2.setSelected(false);
            radioButton_3.setSelected(false);
            
        }
        else if(radioButton_1.isSelected())
        {
            studentAnswer=radioButton_1.getText();
            radioButton.setSelected(false);
            radioButton_2.setSelected(false);
            radioButton_3.setSelected(false);
            
        }
        else if(radioButton_2.isSelected())
        {
            studentAnswer=radioButton_2.getText();
            radioButton.setSelected(false);
            radioButton_1.setSelected(false);
        radioButton_3.setSelected(false);
        }
        else  {
            studentAnswer=radioButton_3.getText();
            radioButton.setSelected(false);
            radioButton_1.setSelected(false);
            radioButton_2.setSelected(false);
        }
        if(db_ans.equals(studentAnswer) )
        {
            //tmarks=tmarks+db_marks;
            //System.out.println("correct");
            tmarks=tmarks+db_marks;
            System.out.println(tmarks);
            System.out.println("correct-first");
        }
    
        count++;
        //System.out.println("first");
        //System.out.println(count);
        //System.out.println("one");
        
        
    }
    catch(Exception a) {
        System.out.println("Error due to :"+a);
    }
    
}
```

}

Comment: I understand that you seek help in debugging your code. Speaking only for myself, in order to help you do that I need to run your code on my computer and reproduce your problem. I can't do that because the code you posted is not a [mcve]. Please try to post code that reproduces your problem. I don't have your database. I don't have your PNG images. I can't just look at the code you posted and discover why it isn't working. That's why debuggers exist, so that you can discover the problem while you run your code. Have you tried running your code with a debugger? Eclipse has a debugger.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I'm just a beginner trying to find my way out, I guess it has got nohting to do with the Database as the questions are rendered dynamically, The problem is that when I choose the right option it doesn't increment the tmarks variable instead sometimes I get 1 or 0

Comment: You've posted a lot of unrunnable code.  You have two choices.  Either learn to use a debugger, or learn the model railroad way of developing an application.  Start building your application again, building a tiny tiny piece of it, and test test test that tiny piece until you're sure that it works correctly.  Then, and only then, build the next tiny piece of code.  Rinse and repeat.

Comment: The Oracle tutorial, [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) will help you learn the correct way to build a Swing GUI.  Skip the Netbeans section.  Also, the [model / view / controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern is an effective pattern to use when constructing a Swing application.